# How to set 'Source version' for AWS CodeBuild project in Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild

I am working with setting up a AWS CodeBuild project in Terraform. Looking at the Terraform docs https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codebuild_project.html I cannot figure out which argument to use to define the source version as highlighted in the image:

[image: Screenshot of the AWS CodeBuild UI]

Is this option supported though Terraform? I would like the CodeBuild project to build from another branch's source code than master.

Comment: There is an open issue for this feature. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9831

Answer (score 3):

You can use **source_version** as it mentioned in the doc you referenced
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codebuild_project.html

```
source_version = "master"
```

Specifying branch in **source_version** works the same way as in AWS console, e.g.

```
source_version = "refs/heads/my-feature-branch"
```

Other examples with tag, pull requests can be found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-source-version.html

Comment: from my understanding, this variable only works with the primary source, not secondary source.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the `source_version` argument

```
resource "aws_codebuild_project" "example" {
  name          = "test-project"
  description   = "test_codebuild_project"
  build_timeout = "5"
  service_role  = "${aws_iam_role.example.arn}"

  source_version = "master"

  environment {
    compute_type                = "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL"
    image                       = "aws/codebuild/standard:1.0"
    type                        = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    image_pull_credentials_type = "CODEBUILD"
...
...

  source {
    type            = "GITHUB"
    location        = "https://github.com/mitchellh/packer.git"
    git_clone_depth = 1

    git_submodules_config {
        fetch_submodules = true
    }
  }
}
```

The feature was in development. Its now available, Please find the docs and issue below.

[[docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/codebuild_project.html#source_version)]  [[issue](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/9877/)]

Comment: from my understanding, this variable only works with the primary source, not secondary source.